# Prove $q = \begin{cases} [{{\frac{a}{b}}}], & b>0 \\[2ex] [\frac{a}{b}]+1 & b<0 \end{cases}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Prove if $$a = bq+r$$     $$0\le r<|b|$$
then
$$q =
\begin{cases}
[{{\frac{a}{b}}}],  & b>0  \\[2ex]
[\frac{a}{b}]+1 &  b<0
\end{cases}$$

I have that $q\leq\frac{a}{|b|}< q+1$
but unable to continue from here.

Comment: Hint: set $t=\frac{r}{b}\in(-1,1)$ and use $\lfloor q+t\rfloor=q+\lfloor t\rfloor$ what can you say about floor of $t$ ?

Comment: The inequality should be $0\le r<|b|$, not $0\geq r<|b|$

Comment: $r<|b|\implies -b<r<b$. When $b<0, -1<\dfrac rb<0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :** ${a \over b} = q + {r \over b}$, so $\lfloor {a \over b} \rfloor = \lfloor q + {r \over b} \rfloor = q + \lfloor {r \over b} \rfloor$. Now, look at the value of $\lfloor {r \over b} \rfloor$ depending on the sign of $b$.